# JQuery Ajax, No callback function is run in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to render a partial view in a container div using JQuery Ajax.
Here's my ajax-call:

```
var href = {
    href: $(this).attr("href").substr(1)
}
var container = $(".customer-main-content-container");
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action(" CustomerMenuSelection ")",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(href),
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("ERROR: " + errorThrown.text());
    },
    success: function (result) {
        container.empty();
        container.html(result).show();

    }
});
```

## Update

Here's my Action code:

```
public ActionResult CustomerMenuSelection(string href)
{
    var user = GetCurrentUser();
    var tempSensorTree = _prtgClient.GetPrtgSensorTree(user.TempPrtgGroupId.ToString());
    var tempDevices = tempSensorTree.Sensortree.Nodes.Group.Device;

    return PartialView("_Monitor", tempDevices);
}
```

I've followed the call through my Action and found that it indeed sends all the correct data back to the view. However, my ajax-call is not running either error- or success-callback and I have no idea why. This is happening when clicking a menu-item, and this same ajax-call works for all other menu-items except this one. I can't find any differences between the pages.
No errors are thrown, the data that I populate the view with is correct. My ajax-call just stops.

So in short, why is my callbacks not triggered?

Grateful for any assistance!
Thanks in advance
Martin Johansson

Comment: Did you look at the request using Fiddler or the browser's built in Network Inspector? Do you get an internal server error on that particular view? You could also try adding a `complete` callback on the `$.ajax` call to see if it gets triggered.

Comment: I saw now after waiting for a long while that I got a Connection Refused error in my browser, but I can't find anything about it in Fiddler.

Comment: Tushar "this" should be my menu-button. The script is in a click-event.

Comment: Have u put breakpoint on action "CustomerMenuSelection" and checked if code is getting executed properly?

Comment: @Tushar ok, well I'm getting the correct values from it atleast. I'm not very good at scopes in js.

Comment: @NitinVarpe Yes I have and the code excecutes as it should and sends the correct data back.

Comment: @MartinJohansson whats result are u returning from action, can u paste your action code here.

Comment: Check you dataType also. "http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/"

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be occurring because of `dataType` you are expecting from server. Try changing it to `"html"` as you are returning partial view from server.

```
dataType: "html"
```

Comment: I used "html" before I started testing. The same issue occurs I'm afraid.

Comment: Have u put breakpoint on both success and error, or console some value in both callback and checked?

Comment: Yes, I've put breakpoints in both error and success, I've put alerts in both and I've checked console and I just get Connection Refused after a few minutes.

Comment: when I set timeout: 5000 it hits this timeout and runs the error function. Results in an alert "ERROR: timeout"

Comment: How long? at 30 sec it still hits the timeout

Comment: Dont know if this will help, but try to use async false in ajax call and also add 'complete' call back and check if its getting hit :(

Comment: I've actually tried async: false. I found that answer in another similar question but it did not work. I will add the complete callback though. I've missed that one.

Comment: @NitinVarpe, your answer works for me. I was using a dataType of "json" in my AJAX call. As soon as I changed to HTML, it was able to hit the callbacks.